# Error in resynthesizer plugi for GIMP 2.8 on Heal Selection

Tags: python, gimp

The plugin files are in the folder home/.gimp-2.8/plug-ins

the script folder is empty

I get the following error , when I run the Heal Selction plugin:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/gimp/2.0/python/gimpfu.py", line 736, in response
    dialog.res = run_script(params)
  File "/usr/lib/gimp/2.0/python/gimpfu.py", line 361, in run_script
    return apply(function, params)
  File "/home/home/.gimp-2.8/plug-ins/plugin-heal-selection.py", line 148, in heal_selection
    pdb.plug_in_resynthesizer(timg, tdrawable, 0,0, useBorder, work_drawable.ID, -1, -1, 0.0, 0.117, 16, 500)
error: procedure not found

Answer (score 0):

Gimp requires the plugin files (.py) have permission "execute".  Use a file browser to query and change the permissions of the files.

This problem might happen if you installed manually by copying files, or if the installer is deficient.  In both cases, an important step was omitted: change the permissions of the installed plugin files.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like the "binary" part of the plugin (`resynthesizer` file) was not registered (the plugin is a binary and several python scrips that call it). See if this file is listed in `~/gimp-2.8/pluginrc`. If it is not, one possibility is that this binary is missing the executable flag (but since the Python files have it that's not too likely). Another possibility is that it cannot run for some reason (missing dependency or else). Start Gimp in a terminal and look for error messages.

If you installed it manually, you can uninstall it and install a proper version with the usual apt tools:

- add [this PPA](https://launchpad.net/~otto-kesselgulasch/+archive/ubuntu/gimp) to your software sources
- install the gimp-plugin-registry package (this will install resynthesizer with a few other useful plugins (and a raft of not-so-useful scripts, unfortunately)).